# What's making the object field automatically change?

Tags: java, oop, logic

I'm making a simple Player/Session system but I just found a logic error even that it seems to me that everything is in order.

Let me describe my idea, I'm still learning how OOP works, that's why I'm practicing in this project :

- First of all I created two classes :
- 1. Class Players
- 2. Class Session

In the Session's class I have a method named joinSession(Session s);
This method will make the player's object join the session like so :

```
Session s1 = new Session();
Player p1 = new Player(name : "Jack");

p1.joinSession(s1);
```

The problem is that in the Session attributes I have a :

```
public Player firstPlayerToJoin;
public Player lastPlayerToJoin;
```

Whenever I make a player join a session everything seems to be fine, Jack is firstPlayerToJoin and lastPlayerToJoin. But the real probleem is when another player decides to join for example :

```
Player p2 = new Player("Rose");    
p2.joinSession(s1);
```

Rose will once again be firstPlayerToJoin and lastPlayerToJoin instead of only being the lastPlayerToJoin.

Here's my code :

First Player class

```
    private static int id;

    private Session session;

    boolean isOnSession = false;

    public static String name;

    public static void say(String message){
        System.out.println(name + " says " + message);
    }

    // Player join session

    public void joinSession(Session s){
        this.session = s;
        System.out.println(name + " joined the session : " + this.session.sessionName );

        System.out.println("Players ONLINE = " + s.playersOnline);
        if( s.playersOnline == 0){
            s.firstPlayerToJoin = this;
            s.lastPlayerToJoin = this;
        }  else {

        s.lastPlayerToJoin = this;}
        s.playersOnline++;
    }


    public void quitSession(){
        this.session = null;
        isOnSession = false;
        System.out.println(name + " left his session.");
    }

    Player(String name){
        id = id++;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public static void showPlayerInfo(Player n){
        System.out.println("========== Player INFO ==========");
        System.out.println("ID : " + id + "\nName : " + name );
    }
}
```

Here's Session class :

```
public class Session {

    int id = 0;

    int maxConnected = 10;

    public int playersOnline = 0;

    String[] playersConnected = new String[maxConnected];

    public String sessionName;
    public Player firstPlayerToJoin;
    public Player lastPlayerToJoin;

    Session(){
        this.id=id++;

this.sessionName = "SESSION"+id;
    }

    public void sessionInfo(){
        System.out.println("======== Session INFO ========");
        System.out.println("Session name : " + sessionName);
        System.out.println("Players online : " + playersOnline);
        System.out.println("First player to join : " + firstPlayerToJoin.name);
        System.out.println("Last player to join : " + lastPlayerToJoin.name);
        System.out.println("==============================");
    }

    int getPlayersOnline(){
        return this.playersOnline;
    }
}
```

And finally the main class and method :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


Player p1 = new Player("Omar");

Session s1 = new Session();

p1.joinSession(s1);

s1.sessionInfo();


Player p2 = new Player("Rick");

p2.joinSession(s1);

s1.sessionInfo();




    }



}
```

If there's any question or confusion about the idea, let me know.

Actual output :

```
Omar joined the session : SESSION0
Players ONLINE = 0
======== Session INFO ========
Session name : SESSION0
Players online : 1
First player to join : Omar
Last player to join : Omar
==============================
Rick joined the session : SESSION0
Players ONLINE = 1
======== Session INFO ========
Session name : SESSION0
Players online : 2
First player to join : Rick
Last player to join : Rick
==============================
```

In the line just before the last one we can see : First player to join : Rick
Player's object p1 overrides the attribute even if there's a condition that's not true.

Comment: The `name` field is `static`. Remove the `static`.

Comment: If you have a debugger you could start a debugging session and try it out ;). You can learn quite a lot by debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to elaborate on RealSkeptic's comment (which I did not figure out until he said it).

You have your name field as static. Currently, if you were to write `(p1 == p2)` you would get `false`, because they are indeed different objects. By making this a static variable, you are setting it for your entire class (Static variables are called *class* variables). What you intended to do is localize your variable so that your individual players would have their own names.

Therefore:

```
public static String name;
```

should be:

```
public String name;
```

Your IDE is probably telling you that you are accessing name in an incorrect way right now. When accessing static variables or methods, you access them through the class themselves rather than objects of that class.

e.g.

```
Player.NAME
```

rather than

```
Player p1 = new Player("tom");
p1.NAME;
```

because, as mentioned, they are for the class themselves rather than local object instantiations of said class. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) is some further reading if you would like:

Comment: Thank you so much for you help ! You saved me a lot of time. Once again thank you.
I was really struggling as I confused between static and constant.
I wanted to make the name impossible to change.